# SharePoint 2013 site collection

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have been looking but have not been able to find it. Is there a way where you can put an html file in a SharePoint 2013 site collection that everyone has access to and then just reference it from different content editor web parts in different site collections?

Answer (score 0):

I usually store my html files for use by content editor web parts in the Site Assets library, and give everyone read access.

Comment: will it work for different site collections?

Comment: Yes, it will work as long as it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

In the OOTB content editor web part, if you specify in  content link a url to a file on another site collection then SharePoint cannot retrieve content from that file. But there are other things you can do like Iframe or creating an app part and deploying it on tenant scope and using the app part instead of Content editor webpart. But these approaches will have its own limitations and is not recommended. Best way is to put the html files in some library inside the site collection.